# Не могу запустить программку. отсутствует ucrtbased.dll

Tags: visual-studio

Я собрал приложение в visual studio. Затем я решил протестировать его на другом компьютере, на котором нет студии.(закинул папку с проектом на рабочий стол.) Попробовал запустить - выдало ошибку (на картинке).
Затем я нашел этот ucrtbased.dll  и закинул его в system32 , но ошибка по-прежнему сохранилось я не могу запустить приложение. Как решить проблему?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попробуйте положить DLL рядом с EXE-файлом, а не в system32

Comment: @PRODIGY не помогло